# Link to change tab image does not work anymore

Tags: facebook, image, tabs

On my page, I'd like to change the tab image of an app. So I clic "edit settings" and get the window to change tab settings but then if I click "Change" for Custom tab image I get an error message "Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

The link looks like this : https://developers.facebook.com/pages/tab_image?pid=[page_id]&app_id=[app_id]

What is wrong with ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a bug, already reported and facebook working on it

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/786503751377430/